# animate callback function not firing - using queue : false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having trouble getting my animate complete function to fire when i add

```
{duration : 2000, queue : false}
```

Example:

```
current.animate({left: "-=600px"}, {duration : 2500, queue : false});
next.animate({left: "-=600px"}, {duration : 2500, queue : false}, function(){
  // Run stuff here once both animations above have finished  
});
```

I have tried .done() with no success,

Any ideas would be grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behaviour by:

```
elem.animate({left: "-=600px"}, {duration : 2500, queue : false, complete: function () {
   //some actions
}});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/byQZp/1/